# How do you see what the firebug errors are?

Tags: html, css, firebug

I'll be working on a page and the firebug icon will have a red circle with an error count in it.  If I click it, nothing happens.  How do you see what the errors are?  On the firebug website it tells you to click the icon.

Thanks!

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/errors

Comment: That's what I said in my post.  I click the red error button but nothing happens.

Comment: You need to click on the code below it to expand the error.

Comment: Actually the description at https://getfirebug.com/errors was incorrect. Clicking the error badge doesn't work at the moment. Therefore I changed the text now. I also [created an issue](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4001) for that some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Firebug Icon, top right, under X button, go to "Console" tab first, check if there are any errors (red lines), go to "Net" tab next, check again for errors (404). You might have a image missing on the website or some external css/js file that dosen't exist or you have a javascript error.

Most common causes are 404 errors or javascript errors.